# mod_jk not tries to connect

Tags: tomcat, mod-jk

I have the following strings in /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log

```
[Fri Apr 05 20:48:04.709 2013] [11848:46912530825504] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2543): (ajp13) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)
[Fri Apr 05 20:48:04.808 2013] [11848:46912530825504] [error] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (448): socket() failed (errno=22)
[Fri Apr 05 20:48:04.808 2013] [11848:46912530825504] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (959): Failed opening socket to (127.0.0.1:9008) (errno=22)
[Fri Apr 05 20:48:04.808 2013] [11848:46912530825504] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1578): (ajp13) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=22)
[Fri Apr 05 20:48:04.808 2013] [11848:46912530825504] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2543): (ajp13) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[Fri Apr 05 20:48:04.808 2013] [11848:46912530825504] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2562): (ajp13) connecting to tomcat failed.
[Fri Apr 05 20:48:04.808 2013] [11848:46912530825504] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2627): Service error=-3 for worker=ajp13
```

the tomcat is listening on port 9008 , i tried to connect with ajpclient and telnet (that seems works),

also I checked with

```
tshark -i any and port 9008
```

It did not catch anything (seems mod_jk even not tried to open connection to tomcat).

So here is question - how can i debug mod_jk more and what could cause such behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by recompile mod_jk.so (one which come with plesk_mod_jk seems incompatible with XEN).